# Ошибка при компиляции - Qt Creator

Tags: qt

Попробовал написать первую программу в Qt Creator  для консоли, в результате ошибки:

```
00:32:14: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled...
00:32:14: Запускается: «C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2012\bin\qmake.exe» E:\YandexDisk\ВУЗ\Информатика\Program\Qt\project_1\untitled\untitled.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2012 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Cannot find file: E:\YandexDisk\ВУЗ\Информатика\Program\Qt\project_1\untitled\untitled.pro.
00:32:14: Процесс «C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2012\bin\qmake.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2012 32bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «qmake»
00:32:14: Прошло времени: 00:00.
```

Код:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QTextStream cout(stdout);

  cout << "Hallo!!!";

  return a.exec();
}
```

Что делать?

Comment: у меня ругался всегда на кириллицу, если она встречалась где-то в пути к проекту... но я creator использовал, и лучше поставьте creator , удобная IDE с очень удобным helpom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, вы должны убедиться, что путь не содержит посторонних символов, включая лишние пробелы. Также может ругаться и на кириллицу в пути к файлу

Во-вторых, попытайте удалить файл `*.pro.user`, а затем вновь скомпилируйтесь

В-третьих, если все-таки что-то не так, скомпилируйте код в командной строке

```
cd путь к проекту
qmake -project
mingw32-make
```

Если проблема осталась, просто переустановите Qt

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я так понял, проблема была с кириллицей в названиях папок...