# Не запускается Qt Creator на Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Всем привет. Пытаюсь установить Qt Creator на windows 8.1 и вроде все скачалось, установилось, но когда запускаю пишет ошибку, как на скрин. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Qt Creator требует windows 10 https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-desktop-platforms.html

Comment: на windows 7 его точно можно установить

Comment: на windows 8.1 тоже можно

Comment: Qt6 не поддерживает Windows7 и 8 - https://www.qt.io/blog/qt6-development-hosts-and-targets

Comment: странно, что при скачивании сайт сам определяет какая операционная система установлена, но после установки у меня появляется такая проблема

Comment: Поставьте более старый QtCreator, основанный на Qt5. Версия 5.15 должна поддерживать Windows 7, 8 и еще поддерживается разработчиками. Если не принимать в внимание санкции.
У меня есть встречный вопрос - Вы используете для установки QtCreator'а "Qt Maintenance Tool"?

Comment: я запускал онлайн и оффлайн установщик, но никак не получается. Установил Qt5, но там со сборкой какая-то проблема пошла, какая-то ошибка с кодом 2 qmake.exe

Comment: "Qt Maintenance Tool" по ip адресу, находящемуся в РФ? блокирует загрузку. 
> Установил Qt5, но там со сборкой какая-то проблема пошла, какая-то ошибка с кодом 2 qmake.exe
Подробнее, пожалуйста, как установили? Сборка чего? Я использую один и тот же Qt на разных машинах под Windows. Просто архив.

Comment: я установил через offline установщик Qt 5.12.12 и вроде все установилось, но когда пытался запустить приложение, то появлялась такая ошибка: "Процесс «C:\Qt\Qt5.12.12\5.12.12\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe» завершился с кодом 2. Ошибка при сборке/развёртывании проекта untitled (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.12.12 MinGW 64-bit) Во время выполнения этапа «qmake»"

Comment: Посмотрите здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478045/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-qt-creator